# Normalize underscore from object's getters before sending them to API

Tags: javascript

I'd like to save a JS-object that makes use of getters and setters using:

```
export default class Item {
    get id () {
        return this._id;
    }

    set id (value) {
        this._id = value;
    }

    get name () {
        return this._name;
    }

    set name (value) {
        this._name = value;
    }
    
    constructor (id, name, children) {
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
        this._children = children;
    }
    
    test () {
        // ...
    }
}


new Item(item.id, item.name, item.children)
```

I need JavaScript getters and setters, because I have to deal with nested items that are calling itself again.

This can be done very easily using something like:

```
get children () {
        return this._children.map((child)=>{
            return new Item(child.id, child.name)
        });
    }
```

I am working with this object and on one point I would like to save it using a call to PHP-API:

```
async save () {
        let method = 'put';
        let url = '/api/item';
        let data = {item: this.item};

        axios ({method, url, data}).then ((response) => {
            // ...
        })
},
```

Now the PHP-API receives an object, whose properties are starting with `_` (like: `_id`), which breaks the PHP-logic at some points.

My question: Is it possible to call all getters to get an object that contains `name` and `id` props instead of `_name` and `_id`?

Comment: My first question is: why you need getters and setters on javascript? I feel that you are trying to use javascript like java.

Comment: Just use one read/write property called `id`. I can't see any benefit in your code to having `get id () { return this._id;`..etc

Comment: I added an example why I need to deal with getters and setters.

Comment: You could override classes `toString` function